# Optimal solution for Weighted points problem

Tags: algorithms, approximation, greedy-algorithms

Problem:

> Fix a constant $k$. Given a set of $2d$-dimensional points $N = \{N_1, N_2, N_3, \dots, N_n\}$, each associated with an arbitrary weight, find a set of points $X = \{X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots, X_k\} \subseteq N$ such that the pairwise distance between any two points in $X$ is at least $D$, and $\sum_{i=1}^k \mathit{Weight}(X_i)$ is maximized.

It would be nice if I could get the exponential solution and then an efficient heuristic so that I can relate to why and how the problem reduces. 
The greedy way to do it would be to sort the points by weight and exclude points which are at distance $D$ from the current point that is being processed. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is a variation of the [Maximal Independent Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set) (MIS) problem in graph theory. To understand that you need to convert your point set $N$ into a graph $G=(N,E)$, where any two vertices $N_1,N_2 \in N$ are connected by an edge if and only if the distance between $N_1$ and $N_2$ is **less** than the threshold $D$. So the set $X$ you are looking for will be one of *independent sets* in the graph $G$. However your case is different, because here:

- Each vertex in $G$ has a numerical weight, and you are trying to maximize the total weight of the independent set instead of its size - this problem is called *Maximal Weighted Independent Set* (MWIS) problem.
- You are looking for an optimal independent set with exactly $k$ vertices.

There is a number of approaches to this class of problems, for example - [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.10834) one. You can try to adapt their approach to your case with *fixed size* of the optimal independent set (which might not exist).

Another approach to this problem uses the fact, that the graph $G$ belongs to a class of [Unit Disk Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk_graph). There is a number of *approximation algorithms*, developed for the MWIS, which use geometric specifics of such graphs - for example, [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.573.9373&rep=rep1&type=pdf) one. Again, they don't limit a number of vertices in the solution set. General discussion of heuristics for problems on unit disk graphs can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9409226).

As for the straightforward **heuristic algorithm** for MWIS with predefined size of the solution - your approach is correct. I'll describe it in more details here. At first a definition:

- An anti-neighborhood $A(N_i)$ of any point $N_i \in N$ is a subset of $N$, such that for any point $N_j \in A(N_i)$ the distance between $N_i$ and $N_j$ is greater or equal than $D$.

We'll assume that each anti-neighborhood is represented by a tree-like data structure, which can perform three operations:

- Build a set from a list of points in $O(n\log n)$ time.
- Find a point (in the set) with maximal weight in $O(1)$ time.
- Compute intersection of two sets in $O(n\log n)$ time.

So, the algorithm:

**Step 1**. Find point $X_1$ with maximal weight and build its anti-neighborhood $A(X_1)$.

**Step 2**. Find point $X_2 \in A(X_1)$ with maximal weight and build the intersection $A(X_1) \cap A(X_2)$.

**...**

**Step $m$**. Find point $X_m \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{m-1}A(X_i)$ with maximal weight and build the intersection $\bigcap_{i=1}^{m}A(X_i)$.

**...**

The intersection of anti-neighborhoods may become empty at some step - in this case the problem doesn't have a solution.

The total time of this algorithm will be $O(kn\log n)$. It's unclear how close this heuristic solution will be to the optimal one.